# При запуске winforms ничего не выводит

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот проблема! прошу помочь

код первого form:

```
namespace algo
{
    public partial class меню : Form
    {
        public меню()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             Сортровка newForm = new Сортровка();
             newForm.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

код programm cs:

```
namespace algo
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form());
        }
    }
}
```

код второй формы (сортровка):

```
namespace algo
{
    public partial class Сортровка : Form
    {
        int i = 0,t;
        string str;
        int[] myArr = new int[10];
        public Сортровка()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Сортровка_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (i < 10)
            {
                myArr[i] = Int32.Parse(textBox2.Text);
                i++;
            } else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
                    {
                        if(myArr[j] < myArr[j+1])
                        {
                            t = myArr[j];
                            myArr[j] = myArr[j + 1];
                            myArr[j + 1] = t;
                        }
                    }
                }
                for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    str = str + " " + myArr[i].ToString();
                }
                jauap.Text = str;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: как минимум для начала  уберите кирилицу из кода в названиях класса

Comment: ок, спасибо!!!!

Comment: Чтобы принять ответ, нужно поставить зеленую галочку слева от ответа.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public partial class меню : Form
                     ^^^^

public partial class Сортровка : Form
                     ^^^^^^^^^

Application.Run(new Form());
                    ^^^^
```

Вы создаете форму - экземпляр базового класса `Form`, на кoтором ничего нет.

Comment: Благодарю, помогло!В рай без очереди

Comment: @DauletBekbaganbetov Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: ок, еще раз спасибо